# How to link the value of a cell with a hyperlink from another cell in WP Data Table?

Tags: wordpress, datatables

How to link the value of a cell with a hyperlink from another cell in WP Data Table?

I have applied the php function but it's not working. THe function is not giving any result nor error.Kindly help to diagnose this problem please.